# how to return people from an array born between certain ages with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm pretty new with js, and I'm trying to filter out people born between certain ages with a function using .filter

```js
const allCoders = [
  {name: 'Ada', born: 1816},
  {name: 'Alice', born: 1990},
  {name: 'Susan', born: 1960},
  {name: 'Eileen', born: 1936},
  {name: 'Zoe', born: 1995},
  {name: 'Charlotte', born: 1986},
]

const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => {
  allCoders.filter(coders = born > startYear && born > endYear)
  return coders
}
```

Comment: The `filter` function expects a function as it's argument, you are passing a boolean

Comment: It would be useful if you stated your question clearly in the *body* of your "post". Otherwise we're left guessing, although the title does divulge the question pretty well. Nevertheless, just dumping some code and one sentence in the title don't make a good question, in my opinion. Have you read [documentation of `filter` at MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made small corrections to the `return` and `function` to `filter`

```js
const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => {
  return coders.filter((coder) => coder.born > startYear && coder.born < endYear);
};
```

You can also shorten this to

```js
const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => coders.filter(({born}) => born > startYear && born < endYear);
```

Comment: There's a typo: `=>` not `=`

Comment: (it was obviously not me)